# Access Android position or accelerometer data log

Tags: android, accelerometer

I was in a car accident on Tuesday evening, and am hoping someone here might be able to help.

I am wondering if it’s possible to gather position or accelerometer data from my phone to help pinpoint the time of impact, which might possibly be used in concert with traffic-light data or video from nearby cameras or other data.

Apologies for the slightly off-topic request. Posting here was recommended by some developer friends of mine.

Comment: As far as I know accelerometer isn't logged. If you want it you'd have to collect it in real-time and potentially store it. But I don't believe that's done by default.

Comment: Also, I'd like to politely let you know that this particular page is a programming site so code questions should go here. Maybe another page would be better suited for this question in particular, not to be rude

Comment: If you'll suggest an alternative, I'll gladly take my query there. I figured if anyone would know, it would be people who understand the code and storage of mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

from your question, yes it can be done by

1. get accelerometer to get it's value from time to time, since when your vehicle is going to crash, the force will give the very high result
2. from my point of view, you need to use compass sensor to help it to calculate properly, (plus GPS sensor, it world be a great help to calculate your current speed)
3. last one, you need to research about how the vehicle crash, when it hit force will go to forth and back, so alot of experiment or good research would be your great help

for starting of accelerometer, (not much of mobile device have this sensor)

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // to get accelerometer censor
    senSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    senAccelerometer = senSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
Sensor mySensor = sensorEvent.sensor;

if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
    float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
    float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
    float z = sensorEvent.values[2];

    long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 100) {
        long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);
        lastUpdate = curTime;

        float speed = Math.abs(x + y + z - last_x - last_y - last_z)/ diffTime * 10000;

        if (speed > MIGHT_BE_CRASHING_THRESHOLD) {
            // do something
        }

        last_x = x;
        last_y = y;
        last_z = z;
    }
}
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
```